# How can I use a Common Lisp (Clozure CL) Library?

Tags: user-interface, frameworks, lisp, common-lisp, clozure-cl

I'm learning Common Lisp (Clozure CL) on the Mac and would like to create a simple GUI. I have downloaded the "ltk" library from CLiki and put it into the project directory at the root level (I assumed I had to do this as I couldn't find instructions for a beginner).

Page 4 of the "LTK - a Lisp binding to the Tk toolkit" documentation says that the library should be compiled using `(compile-file "ltk")` before loading the library using `(load "ltk")`. However, I get this error message:

> Error: File #P"/Users/myName/Desktop/lisp_experiments/GUI_EXAMPLE/ltk" not found
>   While executing: CCL::FCOMP-FIND-FILE, in process Listener(4).
>   Type cmd-. to abort, cmd-\ for a list of available restarts.
>   Type :? for other options.

I also used the full file pathname and got the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Marc

ps - there are almost no noob tutorials about this sort of thing online that takes the user through the process step by step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have downloaded the "ltk" library from CLiki and put it into the project directory at the root level.

Nowadays, this is a step that is seldom required, because libraries are easily accessible using [Quicklisp](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/) (see also [this gif](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/screencast.gif)).
Basically, you should be able to install Quicklisp and run the following:

```
(ql:quickload "ltk")
```

The above downloads, compiles and install Lisp libraries, but not necessarily the required C libraries, which you might need to install separately. If the above works without problem, then the following should work too:

```
(ltk:ltktest)
```

Quicklisp relies on Lisp systems being described with [ASDF](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/) (Another System Definition Facility). The [best practices](https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/asdf/asdf/blob/master/doc/best_practices.md) document is also interesting to read.

In the case of LTK, you can see that `ltk.asd` only specifies one component, `ltk.lisp`. When you install the *system* named "LTK", quicklisp will do all the necessary work to install its dependencies, then compile and load `ltk.lisp`, as described in the manual.

What is unclear is why your explicit `compile-file` failed.

I found the `ltk.lisp` file on my machine; its pathname looks like:

```
#P"/home/user/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/ltk-20150113-http/ltk.lisp"
```

Sure enough, calling `compile-file` with that pathname works and returns another pathname which ends in `.fasl` (the object format). Loading the returned pathname loads the library. Please provide more information about the error so that we can help you debug this problem.

Comment: It's working. Many thanks for your time in writing this. I have followed your instruction and downloaded the quicklisp.lisp file then ran this in Clozure CL. The (ltk:ltktest) ran a demo of the various widgets and 2D canvas. Thanks again.

Comment: Forgot to say that I loaded the setup file after installing quicklisp like this:  (load #P"/Users/myDirectory/quicklisp/setup.lisp"), before running (ql:quickload "ltk").

Comment: @awyr_agored Yes, quicklisp must be loaded every time; that's why can also add the loading part in your personal ccl-init.lisp file (https://ccl.clozure.com/manual/chapter2.4.html)